# .NET WebApi Async Controller Action Executes Forever

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am having a tough time following.NET Async/Await examples, such as the official [MDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) tutorial.

From what I gather, to make a controller action async, I must:

1. Add `async` before the method name.
2. Add `await` before the primary task runs.
3. If I am pulling from a Store or Repository, then I must add `Task.Run()` to the Store method.
4. `async` methods must return `Task<>`

When I do that, with no errors or warnings in the compiler, the method just hangs.    Where am I going wrong?

**PostsController.cs**

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        PostsStore store = new PostsStore();
        List<Post> AsyncResult = await store.GetPosts();
        return Ok(AsyncResult);
    }
```

**PostsStore.cs**

```
    public async Task<List<Post>> GetPosts()
    {
         List<Post> result =  await Task.Run(() => {
            List<Post> posts = new List<Post>();
            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "GetPosts";
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Post post = new Post()
                    {
                        PostId = (int)(dr["PostId"]),
                        Title = dr.SafeGetString("Title"),
                        Body = dr.SafeGetString("Body"),
                        SaveTitle = dr.SafeGetString("SaveTitle"),
                        SaveBody = dr.SafeGetString("SaveBody"),
                        Slug = dr.SafeGetString("Slug"),
                        State = dr.SafeGetString("State"),
                        IsPublished = (bool)(dr["IsPublished"]),
                        LastSaved = (DateTime)(dr["LastSaved"]),
                        CreateDate = (DateTime)(dr["CreateDate"])
                    };
                    posts.Add(post);
                }
                dr.Close();
                connection.Close();
                return posts;
            }

        });

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: There's no need for the Task.Run. And no need to close things when they're wrapped in a using statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `Task.Run` here. You could consider refactoring the method to make use of available async calls.

```
public class PostsStore {
    public async Task<List<Post>> GetPostsAsync() {
        var posts = new List<Post>();
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            var command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "GetPosts";
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            await connection.OpenAsync();
            using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync()) {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync()) {
                    var post = new Post() {
                        PostId = (int)(reader["PostId"]),
                        Title = reader.SafeGetString("Title"),
                        Body = reader.SafeGetString("Body"),
                        SaveTitle = reader.SafeGetString("SaveTitle"),
                        SaveBody = reader.SafeGetString("SaveBody"),
                        Slug = reader.SafeGetString("Slug"),
                        State = reader.SafeGetString("State"),
                        IsPublished = (bool)(reader["IsPublished"]),
                        LastSaved = (DateTime)(reader["LastSaved"]),
                        CreateDate = (DateTime)(reader["CreateDate"])
                    };
                    posts.Add(post);
                }
            }
        }
        return posts;
    }
}
```

Note update of method name to reflect naming convention with async methods

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() {
    var store = new PostsStore();
    var posts = await store.GetPostsAsync();
    return Ok(posts);
}
```

Now with that out of the way consider reviewing/refactoring the above class as there way to many concerns going on in there that can make maintaining it problematic in the future.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll give this a try.   At a high level, what else would you refactor?    How the reader assigns values to a post?